# tkinter Toplevel: trying to understand a window closing quirk

Tags: python, tkinter, window, destroy, toplevel

I created a simple Python/tkinter app.  It opens a primary window using Tk(), and a secondary window using Toplevel.

I noticed unusual behavior: If I try to close out the secondary window before first clicking on the primary window, it closes both windows (which is not the desired behavior).  However, if I first click on the primary window, then close out of the secondary window, the primary window stays open.

The desired behavior is this: I want to be able to close out of the secondary window while keeping the primary window open.  And I don't want to have to click on the primary window first in order for it to stay open. You should be able to go directly to the secondary window and close it out without it also closing out the primary window.

To prevent the unwanted closure of the primary window, I created a hack in the code: I use lift() to swap the stacking order back and forth.  This produces the desired behavior: I can immediately close out the secondary window without first clicking on the primary window, and the primary window still stays open.  Here is the code I wrote:

```
import tkinter as tk

primary = tk.Tk()
primary.title("primary")
primary.geometry("200x200+500+300")

secondary = tk.Toplevel(primary)
secondary.title("secondary")
secondary.wm_geometry("300x300+100+100")

# hack lines: makes it so you can immediately
# close out of secondary without also closing
# out of primary. without these lines of code,
# primary will also close along with secondary
# unless you first click on primary.
primary.lift(secondary)
secondary.lift(primary)

primary.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect without this hack? I'm trying to understand why I need to put this hack in the code.

When people write code that launches a secondary window, it is often in the context of launching it from the primary window.  This forces the user to first click on the primary window. But since I am launching both windows at once, there is no guarantee the user will first click on the primary window.  So maybe that is why I needed to put the lift() hack in.

Not to be fussy, but I am looking for a simple flat-code solution, not a class-oriented one.  So a solution that does not involve the keywords class, self, super(), init, main, anything with double underscores, etc. is hopefully achievable. I'm thinking there may be a small fix or small addition to what I wrote.  But I have no idea what that would be.

I'm using Windows, so I'm not sure if this applies to Mac or Linux.

Comment: It seems to be working well without these lines on osx.

Comment: Thanks, Reblochan.  I'll put in that I'm using Windows.